# I want to replace one part of a string with another sign on a different place in the same string

Tags: regex, date, datetime, mariadb

I have a database with two columns which are related. One is birthdate and the other one is birthdatetr. A number of these in birthdate contains date +" BC" but it needs to be replaced by "-"+date

Birthdatetr contains the dates in true format like YYYY-MM-DD in numbers, the " BC" isn't there. The birthdates can have the following formats

| birthdate | birthdatetr |
| --- | --- |
| Abt 900 BC | 0900-00-00 |
| Bef 55 BC | 0055-00-0 |
| 23 Oct 4004 BC | 4004-10-23 |

It needs to become

| birthdate | birthdatetr |
| --- | --- |
| Abt -900 | 0900-00-00 |
| Bef -55 | 0055-00-0 |
| -23 Oct 4004 | 4004-10-23 |

The Abt, Bef and Aft birthdates are relatively easy to do, it's the 23 Oct 4004 BC which gives me headaches. It's just beyond my skill level

I tried this

update tng_people set deathdate = REPLACE(birthdate, ' 1', ' -1') where birthdate like " % BC";
update tng_people set deathdate = REPLACE(birthdate, ' 2', ' -1') where birthdate like " % BC";
update tng_people set deathdate = REPLACE(birthdate, ' 3', ' -1') where birthdate like " % BC";

and then

update tng_people set deathdate = REPLACE(birthdate, ' BC', '') where birthdate like " % BC";

However that would make 23 Oct 4004 BC look like 23 Oct -4004 which is weird

Anybody has better ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On recent versions of MariaDB, a regex replacement can be used here:

```sql
SELECT
    TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(birthdate,
                   '(.*?)(\\d{1,2} \\w{3} )?(\\d+) BC',
                   '\\1 -\\2\\3')) AS birthdate,
    birthdatetr
FROM tng_people;
```

[image: screen capture of demo link below]

### Demo

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

- `(.*?)` match and capture in `\1` any leading non date portion
- `(\d{1,2} \\w{3} )?` match and capture in `\2` an optional day and 3 letter month
- `(\d+)` match and capture in `\3` the numeric year
- `BC` match literal 'BC'

Then we replace with `\1 -\2\3` to insert a hyphen in front of the start of the date (either short form or long form).

If you really want to *update* the `birthdate` column, then use:

```sql
UPDATE tng_people
SET birthdate = TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(birthdate,
                                    '(.*?)(\\d{1,2} \\w{3} )?(\\d+) BC',
                                    '\\1 -\\2\\3'))
WHERE birthdate LIKE '%BC';
```

Comment: That gives me a list of dates but doesn't replace anything at least not in the database, the output looks like this $1 -$2$3  4004-10-23, thanks for the answer though

Comment: Are you using MariaDB?  Check the demo link in my answer.

Comment: Good question, as far as I can tell in cPanel it just says MySQL

Comment: Found it, MySQL Version  10.5.17-MariaDB-cll-lve

Any advise on that?

Comment: I have updated my answer for MariaDB.  Next time you post please figure out your database version.

Comment: Thanks a million but it still didn't change anything. As for the database version, excuse my ignorance. This is just an elaborate hobby of mine and I am 70 years young. 

So in the output I get the right output but in the database itself nothing changed. Do I have to choose UPDATE instead of SELECT

The coffee is on it's way

Comment: Oh...use an update statement in this case.

Comment: @HennySavenije If this answer resolved your problem, please consider _accepting_ it, by clicking the green checkmark to the left.  This lets other users know that you have verified that the answer works.

Comment: It totally answered my question (there was one unforeseen glitch, Jan 900 BC became Jan -900 but it's good enough for me) However I can't see the green checkmark on the left

Comment: Look under the voting score on the left of the answer.  I was also worried that you would have other edge cases which you forgot to include.  I can only answer to the data which has been shown to me.

Comment: No problem, they were easily solved, My wife bought the coffee as "Henny's friend" :-) My creditcard was declined because I have trouble reading all the Korean when I pay by creditcard and she IS Korean

Comment: If my answer doesn't work on some of your data, edit your question with _all_ the edge cases and I will try to update.

Comment: It doesn't and thanks for the offer but there were so few that I solved it manually

Comment: Basically it didn't work for Jan 70 BC and a few more